# Why is malloc returning NULL here?

Tags: c, pointers, null, malloc

So my program was always returning a segmentation fault, but I couldn't understand why so tried to debug with GDB and it showed me this:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x001a98ef in _int_malloc (av=0x2d8440, bytes=8) at malloc.c:3835
#1  0x001abedc in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=8) at malloc.c:2924
#2  0x0804cd6a in init_capsula (item1_=2, item2_=2)
    at src/modulos/modulos_auxiliares/capsula/capsula.c:25
#3  0x0804d366 in total_dados_produto (f=0x8055838, filial=0x0, mes=6, 
    cod=0xbffff23c "AF1184") at src/modulos/faturacao/faturacao.c:208
#4  0x0804b237 in queries (q=3, c1=0x0, c2=0x0, f=0x8055838, v=0x0) at src/interface.c:815
#5  0x0804b6f4 in menu (c1=0x8055008, c2=0x8055420, f=0x8055838, v=0x0) at src/interface.c:976
#6  0x080487ad in main () at src/interface.c:1037
```

I then identified the source of the problem coming from frame 2 so decided to check that out and got the following output:

```
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0804cd6a in init_capsula (item1_=2, item2_=2)
    at src/modulos/modulos_auxiliares/capsula/capsula.c:25
25          c->item1 = (int*) malloc((sizeof (int))*item1_);
```

It tells me malloc is returning a NULL, however I can't see the problem with this line, everything is proprely initialized as I confirmed with my next action:

```
(gdb) print ((sizeof (int))*item1_)
$1 = 8
```

Why can't malloc allocate a such tiny amount of space? Am I overlokking something really stupid here???

I will put the function init_capsula here (the one where that malloc is) for you guys to see:

```
Capsula init_capsula(int item1_, int item2_){
     Capsula c = (Capsula) malloc (sizeof (struct capsula));

     c->tipo  = -1;

     if (item1_ > 0)
         c->item1 = (int*) malloc((sizeof (int))*item1_); /*Problematic line*/
     else c->item1 = NULL;

     if (item2_ > 0)
         c->item2 = (float*) malloc((sizeof (float))*item2_);
     else c->item2 = NULL;

     c->q1 = 0;
     c->q2 = 0;

     return c;
}
```

Capsula is a pointer to a struct defined like this:

```
struct capsula{
    int tipo;

    int     q1;
    int *item1;

    int       q2;
    float *item2;
 };
```

EDIT:

if I try to run with valgrind using the following command:

```
     valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full make run
```

It outputs this, wich I don't find very helpfull.

```
    make: *** [run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    ==5848== 
    ==5848== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==5848==     in use at exit: 62,771 bytes in 1,819 blocks
    ==5848==   total heap usage: 6,060 allocs, 4,241 frees, 580,609 bytes allocated
    ==5848== 
    ==5848== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==5848==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==5848==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==5848==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==5848==    still reachable: 62,771 bytes in 1,819 blocks
    ==5848==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==5848== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
    ==5848== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
    ==5848== 
    ==5848== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
    ==5848== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

EDIT2:

I finally understood the problem by using valgrind correctly as I was using it on make when I should be using it on the program itself (as indicated on the comments). The problem was on a very different place, on a place I forgot to write a malloc, thanks for everyone that helped, now I finally understand how I should use valgrind

Comment: I don't see where that debug session tells you that `malloc` returned null. It looks like it's dying inside `malloc` itself, pointing to corrupt memory.

Comment: Since you're evidently on GNU/Linux, install Valgrind and run your program under that; then carefully read its error report.  Valgrind is often able to find and pinpoint the undetected problems which lead to crashes and errant behavior later. For instance, a buffer overrun in one module of the program, which trashes the `malloc` heap such that a correct `malloc` call in a totally unrelated module then crashes.

Comment: Is this malloc actually called from user space context?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kaz. I updated the question with the output from valgrind as I don't see what I can understand from this. If you can help me interpret it I would be very thankfull

Comment: jada12276 I don't understand your question can you please rephrase it?

Comment: You appear to be running Valgrind on the `make` utility, not on your program. `make` appears to be clean (no surprise there).  Did you also `gdb make run` to get your program into the debugger? No, right?

Comment: You need to run valgrind *directly on your program*, not on some other program (`make` in this case) that calls yours.

Comment: what happens if you change the problematic line to: c->item1 = malloc(8);  also, make sure you turn off all optimization, and compile with debug symbols.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know it worked like that, I will try using it with the program itself then

Comment: I was assuming some permission problems. But you do malloc earlier which runs fine. My guess is that `item1_` might have an unusually large value which causes malloc to fail.

Comment: I edited the question as running valgrind properlly showed me the problem was on an completelly unrelated line and for some reason the segmentation fault only happened here, thanks for everyone that commented :)

Comment: Please post the `typedef` for `Capsula` as well (i.e., to make sure it's defining a pointer rather then a struct)...

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Post the answer as an answer, not as a mod to the question - which degrades the question.

Comment: Voting "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future visitors".

Comment: Ok I didn't know I was supposed to do that chux. I will do it now

Comment: @Kaz I'm sorry but there is not much else I can do or say because as I said on the answer to my own question the error was pretty unrelated to the posted code and also I explained how I understood that wich may help as it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering to my own question because, as I said on my last edit, I found my answer with help from the comments.

I finally understood the problem by using valgrind correctly as I was using it on make when I should be using it on the program itself (as indicated on the comments). The problem was on a very different place, on a place I forgot to write a malloc so there is no need to get into details about that, thanks for everyone that helped, now I finally understand how I should use valgrind

Answer (score 2):

If the debugger shows you are triggering a segmentation fault on this line:

```
c->item1 = (int*) malloc((sizeof (int))*item1_);
```

It can mean two things:

- `c` is a bad pointer, possibly `NULL`, but the previous statement `c->typo = -1;` should have failed too.
- The arena is possibly corrupted and the problem is in the code executed before getting there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue has to do with the way you're using malloc. Malloc allocates a block of bytes of memory, **returning a pointer** to the beginning of the block. You should write:

```cpp
Capsula * c = (Capsula *) malloc (sizeof (struct capsula));
```

Actually, unless c is a pointer to a structure, it's illegal to write **c->tipo  = -1;**. For example, the -> operator in **c->tipo** is a shortcut for ***(c).tipo**.

Comment: If the upper-cased `Capsula` is `typedef struct capsula *Capsula`, there isn't anything wrong.

Comment: The OP is most likely hiding pointers behind typedefs: `typedef struct capsula * Capsula;`.  This is considered bad style and your misinterpretation is the reason why it is counterproductive.

Comment: What you say is correct however my struct is capsula and Capsula is a pointer to it as I said on my question. But thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @Kaz, I don't think we should down-vote for mistakes in code that is used to point at a problem. If the answer is correct, that code can be rectified instead. Finding the issue is the real challenge and I doubt we should be requiring people to test the code they use in the answers (I'm not talking about an answer with a long "this code will work for you" code block).

Comment: @Myst, Kaz didn't say his code was wrong, Oladodja just misinterpretated like chqrlie and kaz said. And actually on Oladodja's code there is nothing wrong.